# Go install not working on Window?

Tags: windows, go

I just installed Golang on my Windows box today, and I have my `%GOPATH%` set. However, when I run `go install {...}` for various binaries, Windows can't find the executables. My `%GOROOT%` is `C:\Go`, the default .msi install location.

```
PS C:\Users\{user}\Development\go> ls
    Directory: C:\Users\{user}\Development\go


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        12/11/2015   9:02 PM            bin
d----        12/11/2015  11:08 AM            pkg
d----        12/11/2015  11:08 AM            src
C:\Users\{user}\Development\go>echo %GOPATH%
C:\Users\{user}\Development\go
```

Do I have the environmental variables set incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Windows can't find the executables

If you mean the executable built from your go programs (by `go install`) and delivered by Go in `%GOPATH%\bin`, all you need is to add to your `PATH` environment variable `%GOPATH%\bin` (in addition of `%GOROOT%\bin`)

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%GOPATH%\bin
cd %GOPATH%\src\path\to\a\go\project
go install
```

Then you can call your executable, and Windows will find it in `%GOPATH%\bin` (the `C:\Users\{user}\Development\go\bin` folder)

Comment: Ah...that's what I was missing. Thanks!